# How to get kotlin element symbol name from a PsiElement from textOffset/PsiNamedElement

Tags: kotlin

PsiElement getText/getTextRange will return the entire element definition. For example:

```
public class Foo{}
```

it will return the entire element `public class Foo{}` but I just want extract the name identifier Foo. I use api getTextOffset to find the start of the name identifier, but not able to find the endOffset unless I classify the element and check

```
if (psiElement is PsiNamedElement)
      
   
{
  endOffset = psiElement.textOffset + psiElement.name.length - 1
}
```

is there a better way to only extract the symbol name?